# Create Custom Methods in ASP Web API Controller and retrieve their data

Tags: c#, api

I Have a **C# WinForms application** and in a form I want to consume (Get) some data from an **ASP Web API application**.

in Web API I have a `controller` named **Session** inside this controller I have two methods as shown below :

```
        public int Create()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int New_ID = random.Next();
        return New_ID ;
    }
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Catch this data";
    }
```

So the problem is when I use browser URL (For testing) to access to controller (Session)

**URL :** `http://localhost:52626/api/Session`

I got
[image]

And when I want to access to controller (Session) especially Create Function

**URL :** `http://localhost:52626/api/Session/Create`

I got

[image]

**The global question is how can I create my own methods and access to it without depending on Get ?**

Comment: A URL you have client doing a Request and a getting back a Response.  Your controller is a Server which accepts the request and returns the response.

Comment: You need to define a route to each method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser always fires a **GET**. Web-API by default selects the method to be called using the HTTP verb (**GET** in your case) of request. Hence it always lands in "Get" method. To make Web-API point to your method you need to define a route. Use below:

```
        [Route("api/session/Create")]
        [HttpGet]
        public int Create()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int New_ID = random.Next();
            return New_ID;
        }
```

To better understand route based selection, read this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection